Equation of the hole in a pipe where another pipe of smaller diameter can be inserted
I am interested in the equation of the hole in a pipe 1 where another pipe 2 of smaller diameter can be inserted into, the pipe 2 being at an angle Alpha with the main pipe
I attach a picture which shows the question when the angle is less than 90 degrees:

I am working on generating a G-code for a plasma CNC machine that cuts the necessary hole in the larger cylinder so that the smaller cylinder can be inserted into, usually at an angle < 90 degrees with the X+ axis and welded
regards


Assuming you look from infinitely far away, you see a circle, obviously, since you're just looking along the sides of the small pipe. 2. Neither. The widest part of the oval will be closer to the $-x$ end.

